# Подключение приложения Xamarin к базе данных SQL

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, xamarin.forms

имеется приложение на Asp.net Core mvc, с базой данных, которая создана при помощи sql server, взаимодействие с базой данных  происходит при помощи Entity Framework. Как подключить приложение на Xamarin к данной базе данных?

Comment: Зачем подключать его к базе, может, лучше связать с приложением?

Comment: не подскажите, как это можно сделать? я новичок, и впервые делаю мобильное приложение

Comment: У вас БД есть? есть. У вас ASP.NET приложение есть? Тоже есть. Какие пролемы с тем, чтобы вызывать ваше asp.net приложение из мобильного приложения и получать нужные вам данные?

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста поподробнее, я не совсем вас понимаю